# CSS form styling, text and button together

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, css-selectors

[image: troubleshoot]

I am trying to have the left firefox window look exactly like the subscribe form on the right.
Yet i cant seem to align it in the middle properly, or have them "merged"or stuck together like in the example.
I can exit the font later but i just need it to fit.
Tried flex on the parent div of the form "subscribeForm" but that just results in them beeing drawn in a straight row as 1 element.

Can anyone help me with this?

### DEMO

```css
.aboutSub{
    background-color: #696969;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:2rem;
}

 .subscribeForm{
    width: 100vw;     
}
form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;       
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1 solid black;
    width:100vw;
}
input[type=text] {
    width:90%;

}
/* input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#333;
} */

input[type=submit] {
    width:90%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="aboutSub">
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p>Bakery was formed in 2014 after the merger of the two largest bakeries in the country; The Creative
        Muffin and Westcoast Bread. With over 200 employees, there isn't a job too big or too ambitious.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Subscribe</h2>
      <p>Give us your email, and we shall send regular updates for new stuff and events.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="subscribeForm">
      <form action="#">
        <label for="e-mail"></label>
        <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail">
        <input type="submit" value="subscribe">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 things only:

- Put box-sizing:border-box on content
- Make submit button border: 0
- Give border to email input except on the bottom.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aboutSub {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.subscribeForm {
  width: 100vw;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #3b3b3b;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 8px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  background: transparent;
}


/* input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#333;
} */

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 90%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="aboutSub">
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p>Bakery was formed in 2014 after the merger of the two largest bakeries in the country; The Creative Muffin and Westcoast Bread. With over 200 employees, there isn't a job too big or too ambitious.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Subscribe</h2>
      <p>Give us your email, and we shall send regular updates for new stuff and events.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="subscribeForm">
      <form action="#">
        <label for="e-mail"></label>
        <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail">
        <input type="submit" value="subscribe">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is your edited code: https://codepen.io/uiexpo/pen/dydRRPY

Answer (score 0):

You should remove width from the flex elements since it will already fill the container because of being an flex item.

```
.aboutSub {
    background-color: #696969;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:2rem;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;       
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1 solid black;
}
```

The gap between two inputs is probably caused by default browser styling. Since your email input is going to have a border I would set the same border to both inputs to fix it and make submit the same color (as it is in your goal layout).

```
input[type=text], input[type=submit] {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray; 
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Now both inputs will be aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, it's fixed.
Combined some solutions
THANKS Everyone!.
Problem was in the width's of the form, created an overflow somehow.  and that i missed a padding in the example of the parent. Also border-box is something i always do.

THANKS!

CSS

```
.aboutSub{
padding:3rem;
background-color: #696969;
color: white;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: column;
gap:2rem;
}
form {    
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;       
flex-direction: column;   
border: 1px solid black;
}
input[type=text] {
width:100%;
border:0;
padding:0;    
}
input[type=submit] {
width:100%;
border:0;
padding:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="aboutSub">
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>Bakery was formed in 2014 after the merger of the two largest bakeries in the country; The Creative
                Muffin and Westcoast Bread. With over 200 employees, there isn't a job too big or too ambitious.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Subscribe</h2>
            <p>Give us your email, and we shall send regular updates for new stuff and events.</p>

        </div>

        <form action="#">
            <label for="e-mail"></label>
            <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail">
            <input type="submit" value="subscribe">
        </form>

    </div>
</section>
```

[image]